# importerror cannot import name candlestick

Tags: python, candlestick-chart

I got an error message from Python:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "stock_script.py", line 9, in <module>  
>     from matplotlib.finance import candlestick  
> ImportError: cannot import name candlestick
> ```

Why?

Comment: Because `candlestick` isn't installed properly?

Comment: You should rework your question according to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib code has been changed...
Go into the script and replace "candlestick" by "candlestick_ohlc"

So it should read:

from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc

candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ...

Answer (score 1):

Not very nice changing the name and breaking existing code...

I have fixed this by changing the import like this.

`from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc as candlestick`

No further changes are then needed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an underscore to it to use this same library:

```
from matplotlib.finance import _candlestick
```